# PL/SQL How to use a certain set of strings (columns) as a column names in a stored procedure. (column names are ',' seperated)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a list of columns stored into a string:

```
str VARCHAR2(100) = 'col1, col2, col3';
```

And I want to perform operation such as:

```
SELECT <columns from str> FROM source_table;
```

I need to know how to access these columns from the str and can be used to access my source table with only desired columns.

Is there any way?

Comment: PLease take the [tour] and read [ask] and provide more details.  It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: look at execute immediate

Comment: [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73)

Answer (score 0):

Try this little example to help get your head around it.

Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE src_tbl
(
  COL1  NUMBER,
  COL2  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)
```

Add a couple of rows to it

```
Insert into src_tbl (COL1, COL2) Values (1, 'item1');
Insert into src_tbl (COL1, COL2) Values (2, 'item2');
COMMIT;
```

Run this block which defines a column list in a variable, builds the query dynamically, then runs it, putting the output into a record that is then printed.

Note this example is very simple and just works for a single matching record.  To return multiple records you'll need to return into a collection but that is beyond the scope of this post.

```
declare
  col_list VARCHAR2(100) := 'col2, col1';
  stmt varchar2(500);
  src_tbl_rec src_tbl%ROWTYPE;
begin
  stmt := 'SELECT '|| col_list || ' from src_tbl where col1 = 1';
  execute immediate stmt into src_tbl_rec;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(src_tbl_rec.col1||' - '||src_tbl_rec.col2);
end;
```

Output

```
1 - item1
```